# How do you check if a specific user joined a voice chanel in discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to make a bot that sends different messages depending on who joins a voice chat, the bot also needs to join that specific voice chat.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("project is running")
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
})




const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents:['Guilds', 'GuildMessages', 'MessageContent']});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {  
   if(message.author.username==="User123") //om is user 123 joins
  {       
    const vchannel = message.member.voice.channel
    vchannel.join()
    message.channel.send("user specific message");
  }
   
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.